# window.showModalDialog and whatever permutation of WebBrowser

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Is there anyway to get access to or control the windows that pops up from JS calling window.showModalDialog?

I am currently using the WPF webbrowser which as I've noticed has very limited help in this area so I tried switching over to the Forms.WebBrowser version but that also doesn't seem to help me... I tried all the different permutations of newwindow events but they only fire when a completely new IE window pops up like from a _blank target...

The window that pops up has a series of check boxes I need to click through and then click OK from code

the best thing I've figured out as a plan so far is to inject some JS that emulates the return parameter of the dialog. But I was curious if there's a way to control or access this dialog from code...